# Nagios returning "connect to address and port 443: Connection refused"

Tags: nagios

I have added https url to nagios for monitoring. The url should ideally return 302 Status code. But the response keeps fluctuating from "HTTP 302" to "connect to address and port 443: Connection refused HTTP CRITICAL - Unable to open TCP socket"

Service status for both the responses:

```
1.
{
    host_name="myURL"
    service_description=HTTP
    modified_attributes=0
    check_command=check_http! --expect=302 --ssl
    check_period=24x7
    notification_period=24x7
    check_interval=5.000000
    retry_interval=1.000000
    event_handler=
    has_been_checked=1
    should_be_scheduled=1
    check_execution_time=0.007
    check_latency=0.000
    check_type=0
    current_state=2
    last_hard_state=0
    last_event_id=6158
    current_event_id=6161
    current_problem_id=3057
    last_problem_id=3054
    current_attempt=3
    max_attempts=4
    state_type=0
    last_state_change=1533119301
    last_hard_state_change=1533117561
    last_time_ok=1533119301
    last_time_warning=0
    last_time_unknown=0
    last_time_critical=1533119421
    plugin_output=connect to address and port 443: Connection refused
    long_plugin_output=HTTP CRITICAL - Unable to open TCP socket
    performance_data=
    last_check=1533119421
    next_check=1533119481
    check_options=0
    current_notification_number=0
    current_notification_id=0
    last_notification=0
    next_notification=0
    no_more_notifications=0
    notifications_enabled=0
    active_checks_enabled=1
    passive_checks_enabled=1
    event_handler_enabled=1
    problem_has_been_acknowledged=0
    acknowledgement_type=0
    flap_detection_enabled=1
    process_performance_data=1
    obsess=1
    last_update=1533119435
    is_flapping=1
    percent_state_change=20.79
    scheduled_downtime_depth=0
    }

2.
{
    host_name="myURL"
    service_description=HTTP
    modified_attributes=0
    check_command=check_http! --expect=302 --ssl
    check_period=24x7
    notification_period=24x7
    check_interval=5.000000
    retry_interval=1.000000
    event_handler=
    has_been_checked=1
    should_be_scheduled=1
    check_execution_time=0.062
    check_latency=0.001
    check_type=0
    current_state=0
    last_hard_state=0
    last_event_id=6161
    current_event_id=6162
    current_problem_id=0
    last_problem_id=3057
    current_attempt=1
    max_attempts=4
    state_type=1
    last_state_change=1533119481
    last_hard_state_change=1533117561
    last_time_ok=1533119301
    last_time_warning=0
    last_time_unknown=0
    last_time_critical=1533119481
    plugin_output=HTTP OK: Status line output matched "302" - HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily - 763 bytes in 0.059 second response time
    long_plugin_output=
    performance_data=time=0.058644s;;;0.000000 size=763B;;;0
    last_check=1533119481
    next_check=1533119781
    check_options=0
    current_notification_number=0
    current_notification_id=0
    last_notification=0
    next_notification=0
    no_more_notifications=0
    notifications_enabled=0
    active_checks_enabled=1
    passive_checks_enabled=1
    event_handler_enabled=1
    problem_has_been_acknowledged=0
    acknowledgement_type=0
    flap_detection_enabled=1
    process_performance_data=1
    obsess=1
    last_update=1533119615
    is_flapping=1
    percent_state_change=20.26
    scheduled_downtime_depth=0
    }
```

This is happening with only a couple of url's.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You would get **Connection refused** if the port wasn't open on the remote computer or blocked via firewall, e.g. the httpd service wasn't running.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Scott Wilkerson . I'm getting two different outputs for the same command. If the port was not open, shouldn't i be getting the same "Connection refused" every time.?

Comment: Not if the state of the port you are connecting to changes... For example, this is a http check and it will return OK if it can connect, but if you stop the webserver, or it rejects the connection because of another issue you would get a CRITICAL and could get "Connection refused"